# Visual SourceSafe doesn't create root folder

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I'm working with **Visual SourceSafe** but I'm getting a problem because when I try to download a project using Get the Last Version **doesn't create the root folder**, this create all subfolders. For example:

[image]

If I use "*Get Last Version*" on the folder "*VisualStudio*" doens't create a folder called *IMECPP*, create all the subfolders (CD, CN, EntidadesEmpresariales)...

What could be the problem?

(I can't change to git or others, I have to use SourceSafe).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog box of "Get Last Version" you may specify the destination folder in the field "To:", it should include the highest folder "IMECPP".
If this folder does not already exist in your local drive, then VSS will create it (and all the path before).
You also have to cross check the "recursive option".
If you click on "Extended>>" you will have access to 2 more options that can also change the behaviour of the command.